# Assign a different image to each div by browsing a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is my HTML:

```
<li class="pusher"></li>
<li>
    <div>
        <img src="~/Images/photo1.jpg" />
        <h1>This is a title a bit longer</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have a folder full of images that are named photo1.jpg, photo2.jpg etc, and i would like to find a way to make my img src take a different picture for each div that my document contains.

I know it's about the `.each` function but really I don't know how to use it well with an attribute change.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample JQuery code that you can try:

```
var count = 1;
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'Images/photo' + count + '.jpg');
  count++;
});
```

Of course, it assumes that same HTML (as asked in question) is repeated, and that each LI has one `img` tag.

Comment: Oh yes thank you ! I was on the way to code this Jquery but it wasnt working, finaly the count that u put is working well ! Thank you verry much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on varying the number of photos in your folder, you can do it rather statically by giving each of your `<img>` elements an `id` of `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` and so on.

then it's a simple for loop:

```
for (i=1; i<(number of images); i++)
{
  document.getElementById(i).src="/sourcefolder/photo"+i+".jpg"
}
```

Let me know how that works for you?

Comment: In this case, `h1` and `p` tags would get removed, as you have assigned ID to `div` tag and you are setting HTML inside div tag.

Comment: You're right. I edited my original solution now to only change the `<img>` elements instead of the `<div>` contents. Of course this is assuming the page is initialized with enough `<div>` and `<img>` elements rather than generating new ones at run time